# multiply array using each on ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I've been stuck on this problem. I'd appreciate any help.

**The instructions**
"Use the .each method on the odds array to print out double the value of each item of the array. In other words, multiply each item by 2.

Make sure to use print rather than puts, so your output appears on one line."

**My code**

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]

odds.each do |placeholder|
    odds *= 2
    print odds
end
```

Comment: print `placeholder`, not `odds`

Comment: Try inserting `puts "placeholder=#{placeholder]"` as the first line of the block.

Answer (score 5):

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.each do |placeholder|
  odds *= 2
  print odds
end
```

Your usage of `#each` is correct here, but remember that `#each` receives an `::Enumerable` object, the block passed in uses the variable `placeholder` to encapsulate the value in the `::Array` at the current point of the iteration. Therefore you would need to use `placeholder` to retrieve the value you want to double, and not `odds` because `odds` would still be an `::Array` within the `::Enumerable` function `#each`.

This code can be written in two lines as follows:

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.each {|placeholder| print placeholder * 2 }
```

Strictly speaking, `#map` would be the preferred method for doing this.

Comment: Why do you (and other posters) think `map ` is to be preferred? I don't agree. `[1,3,5,7,9].map{|placeholder| print placeholder * 2 }` creates a useless array of `nils`, which is referenced by nothing . The whole purpose of `map` is to create an array - but in this case nobody asked for an array. `each` is fine.

Comment: @steenslag this would work nicely though `print *odds.map{|x| x * 2}` though I do agree since the OP said using `each` although I guess technically pretty much all `Enumerable` methods use each

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html Refer to the ::Array #map function in ruby docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
odds.each { |x| print "#{x*2}" }
```

ruby-ish way:

```
print odds.map {|x| x*2}.join(' ')
```

Comment: `each` is not needed for `map`. `each` will create an `Enumerator` which will allow `map` to work because `Enumerator` includes the `Enumberable` module but since `Array` also includes `Enumerable` just `map` would be sufficient.

Comment: awesome. :) even better

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to multiply the `Array` `odds` by two in each iteration in your code. The `do |placeholder|` means 'for each item in the array, give me the single element and call it `placeholder`'.

So you would need to use `placeholder *= 2`.

However, since you aren't mutating the original value in `odds`, you can shorten your inner block by just `print placeholder * 2`.

Additionally, while the question might be saying to use `:each`, `:map` is much more canonical to what you are doing. Using map would allow you to double each element like so:

```
odds.map{ |i| i*2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`odds` is your array. `placeholder` represents a value from the array. Without explicitly providing you the answer, what you want to do is multiply the value by 2, not the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here Iam done that on succesfully

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.each do |x|
    x *= 2
    print x
end
```